# Access Kubernetes namespace dynamically

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Is it possible to define ingresses such that it point to different namespaces.

e.g.
Same application running for different customers.
Namespaces - Customer1, Customer2

Both have the same apis - /api/v1/images/

Both are hosted on same cluster - api-dev

Now can we direct traffic to different namespaces depending on the name of customer in the api
e.g

Customer1/api/v1/images/- will show images stored in Customer1 namespace

Customer2/api/v1/images/- will show images stored in Customer2 namespace

The Customer name will be provided by another service running in default namespace

[image]

Comment: yes you can. You will need to do it through headless services without selector in the same namespace as the Ingress. Then you would create Endpoint objects, pointing to the services in other namespaces. K8s team already told couple of years ago that Ingress object introduces a huge security hole if allowing it to trespass namespaces, so there is no native way of doing this, and there is no other way either.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

1. You can create a DNS entry per `Service` in each namespace and have each namespace have its own LoadBalancer (perhaps costly but each app can be independently scaled etc)
2. You can use Istio and create a single `Gateway` and create a `VirtualServices` to each `Namespace`. This allows one DNS to your cluster and Istio can redirect traffic to each namespace without having to update the cluster DNS
3. You can write a short CodeZero provisioner for your app (https://github.com/c6o/provisioners) and CodeZero will automatically do the DNS/ingress for each app instance in each namespace. You can test this out using an existing app